# 10 digits android

Tags: java, android, string, math, double

I am Writing a Android calculator and would like to limit the number of charicters that are outputted to 10
eg:
1: ans = 1.23456789101
should show 1.23456789
2: ans = 1234.56789101
should show 1234.56789
3: ans = 123456789101
should show 1234567890
this is what i have so far but it only works for 1 digit before "."

```
        ans = (double)Math.round(ans * 100000000) / 100000000;
        String output = String.valueOf(ans);
        if(output.endsWith(".0")){
            output=output.substring(0, output.length()-2);
        }
        textbox.setText(output);
```

how would i go about doing this

Comment: Could you format your code so it's not all mashed up on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a series of if statements about the value, combined with DecimalFormat

```
if (value >= 10 && value < 100) DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#########");
else if (value >= 100 && value < 1000)) DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
else if (value >= 1000 && value < 10000)) DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#######");

etc etc

textBox.setText(String.valueOf(formatter.format(value));
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way of handling this, but this would at least work.   You can also, for the values over 10 digits, chain in the else if's to include some truncating code.

Comment: thank you that should work how would i get it to change to scientific if it is longer than 10 digits

Comment: Again, i'm new to android, and there's probably a more elegant way to do this, but the DecimalFormat class looks like it can accept something like DecimalFormat("0.######E0")  In your implementation with max 10 spacing, you'd probably need another few if statements to ensure that E8 and E13 and E124 have the correct amount of #'s

Comment: Why are you asking a followup question within a comment?  I would suggest deleting this entire question and asking, specifically, what you want answered, or asking this followup question as a new question entirely. Have you read the FAQs on how to pose a question?

Comment: @Stealth Rabbi - followup and/or clarification to existing questions logically should stay inside their own question, right?  Don't get upset and downrate for personal reasons...  Help solve problems

Comment: Downvote was because the question isn't contained in the question post, but rather, contained in comments. I did answer the original question as it's posed, see my post below.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) class. It will let you customize the display of your values.  Don't hurt yousefl by doing substringing off of the decimal place, my good sir. Also, read up on the rounding behavior to make sure it will do what you want (you provide the DecimalFormat with an unrounded value).

```
double d = 1234.543534535345345345;
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); // round to 2 decimals
System.Out.Printline(Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
```

Comment: i want to round to as many characters that will fit on the screen not just the same every time and the only getting rid of the decimal place so I don't get #.0

Comment: That should have been in your initial question. The topic of this post is "8 digit android", and then your question text says you want to limit the output to 10. Which is it?

Comment: Also, do you really want to limit the precision of your program based on someone's screen width? I'm not sure what someone would be doing on an Android device that would require 8, 10, or however many decimal places you think. The default android calculator goes to 7 dcimal places. Do you also plan on changing this based on the orientation of the device?

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Someone should be able to figure out what your question is by reading your first post, not the comments. The question says you want 10 decimal places. So you want it at a static 10?  How large can a number be to the left of a decimal place?
1.1234567891
3454354535.1234567890

Comment: the built in android calculator goes to 12 decimal points on the tablet I am using I just want all the numbers to fit on screen so scrolling is not required

Comment: So why isn't that in the information about scrolling text, etc. in the original post? The question needs to be in the question post so people reading this later can see what you're asking.